# DESeq2 DDS filter error message using Dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

```
dds$Description <- select(dds, Description == "Mammary_Tumor", "Mammary_Normal")
ddstxnmam <- DESeq2:: DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = dds,
                                              colData = cd,
                                              design = condition)
ddstxnmam <- DESeq2:: DESeq(ddstxnmam)
```

> Error in UseMethod("select") :
> no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "character"

How can I alter the code to correctly filter my dds for the Mammary Tumor and Mammary Normal Samples?

Comment: Please make your question reproducible so others can help. See more here [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select is for selecting columns, you are filtering here ( at least it looks like that since you did not provide any description and did not add a dataset).

```
dds$Description <- dds %>% filter(Description %in% c("Mammary_Tumor", "Mammary_Normal"))
```